# I Have an idea , it is similar to a couple of other patented ideas

Tags: development, airstatorrotor

The idea simply involves using compressed air to spin (a) stator/rotor(s) and, in  turn, charge (a) battery (ies) that powers the electric motor. I want to contact these people and move the ideas/patent into the market. Any ideas on how to start locating these people?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. I do not see the patent number in your post.

Comment: Contact information (for US patents) can be found in the PAIR database -- http://www.uspto.gov/patents/process/status/index.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Contact information (for US patents) can be found in the PAIR database -- http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair